# How do I run a command but show no output?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to run the command `airmon-ng start wlan0` but all I want to see is "Please wait, Monitor Mode is starting". I want to run the command in the background while displaying "Please wait, Monitor Mode is starting". I don't want to see any output from the command `airmon-ng start wlan0`. I have tried many ways of doing this but with no luck if anyone knows how that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please wait, Monitor Mode is starting"
airmon-ng start wlan0 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null &
```